# Mongo many to many

Tags: mongodb, optimization, schema, database

I'm trying to model a many to many relationship where a Customer 'loves' a Food.

I'm expecting to get lots (millions) of these relationships so I didn't want them to all end up in one join table that couldn't scale.

I created two document collections,

```
Customers
 - name etc 
 - countOfLoves
 - loves [ ... ]
```

and

```
Foods
 - name etc
 - countOfLoves
 - loves [ ... ]
```

Inside each document is a subdocument collection of 'loves' representing the relationships and a count to quickly get totals.

I had assumed that this would scale well because instead of a queries on a table with millions of rows I could just get a single document and it's subarray. However, I'm running into a problem when a customer starts to love lots of foods (and, inversely, when a food is loved by lots of customers)

Here is the query to update a customer document when a new food is loved. In this case the customer already loves 7000 other foods :

```
 query: { _id: "354286" } 
update: { $push: { loves: { foodID: "354286", location: [ 55.752197, 37.6156 ] } }, $inc: { countOfLoves: 1 } }
nscanned:1 nupdated:1 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) w:10135199 10137ms
```

There are two questions here really,

a) Why is this taking 10 seconds - is there something about $push that I don't know

b) Is there a better schema for Mongo that can model this kind of relationship?

(and, I guess (c) - Am I over optimising - should I just make a loves join table and it will be fine?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the reason I am seeing it to be slow if the size of document is large not to fit in its place it will be moved to another place. This may be on of the reason of 10 seconds.  You can see the similar discussion here : https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mongodb-user/FnL0mDWs5w0 . One of the solution to have array filed with dummy values while creating and you use some how to update them not adding new loves . In this case may be you have to opt for one more collection as Loves where for each love you will store the customer Id and what he loves

Comment: An alternative to creating a 3rd collection would be to allow multiple records for each food and customer. In this case you could put a limit on the # of loves for each collection (10 for example), pad for that number and then move to a new record once all slots were full. You would want a "full" flag in each document which would be part of your lookup index to allow for fast insertion.

Comment: Hmmm this looks nice option but what are the possible way of padding it nice way any idea ?

Comment: See the following page which provides guidance on manual padding: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/#can-i-manually-pad-documents-to-prevent-moves-during-updates